# Close process when a separate process closes

Tags: batch-file, process, task, scheduler

So I use task scheduler to run a specific file (c:\Newfile.exe) after a specific program has been started (c:\Program.exe).

I'd like to know how I can close "Newfile.exe" when "Program.exe" closes. I know this can't be done with task scheduler, does anyone know of a way to achieve this scenario outcome?

Kind regards

Tried using task scheduler

Comment: Did you program `program.exe`? If so use a job object.

Comment: @Noodles Those are just examples, the real files are buried in their own separate directories. I used those examples to simplify the thread so people could understand easier.

"Program.exe" is a software on my PC, I didn't code it.
"Newfile.exe" is an AHK script.

Comment: You could write a starter program that starts both programs and terminates one when the other terminates.

Answer (score 0):

This program runs waiting for a program to exit, checks if it was Notepad.exe and if so terminates MyProgram.exe. Use an `Exit Do` after terminating your program to also quit the script.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    If lcase(objReceivedEvent.ProcessName) = lcase("Notepad.exe") then 
        Msgbox "Process exited with exit code " & objReceivedEvent.ExitStatus
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process where ProcessName=MyProgram.exe")
        For Each itm in ColItems
             itm.Terminate
        Next
    End If
Loop
```