# Create an vbs-script that waits for a specific file to run, do something and wait for termination

Tags: vbscript

this is my first question, so don't judge too hard on me ;)

I'm trying to create an VBS that waits for an specific process to run (e.g. C:\Program Files\MyApp\AppName.exe), the path is important: It should't react if somewhere else is started a process with the same name. If it founds the aimed process with the right directory, then it should start another vbs-script that wait for the stop of the app with the same conditions as its start.

Here is what I'm reached for now (dont relate on it, it didn't work but it should give an idea):

```
Option Explicit
'On Error Resume Next


Dim wshshell, objShell, Systemdrive, Username, AppData, oFSO, oShell,  RIGHTHERE, strComputer, objWMI, ColOSs, OS, OSType, service, AppName, Process, AppName2, objReg, Path, PathCompare, colItems, objItem, ObjWMIService

SET WshShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
RIGHTHERE = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - Len(WScript.ScriptName))


set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

AppName = "AppName.exe"

Function IsAppRunning(AppName)
    for Each Process in Service.Instancesof("Win32_Process")
        If UCase(Process.Name) = UCase(AppName) then
Path = Process.ExecutablePath
' msgbox "Paths name is...: " & Path
PathCompare=RIGHTHERE & AppName
' msgbox RIGHTHERE & AppName
        If UCase(Path) = UCase(PathCompare) then
' Process "AppName.exe" found with same path as VBS
' msgbox "Paths are identical!"
IsAppRunning = True

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "ReportMe.vbs",1,True


Exit function
' VBS is automatically terminated here, no idea why
else
' Process name is "AppName.exe", but its file path is not the same as that of the VBS
' msgbox "No match - Go to next process!"  
end if 
else
' here the found process is not even called "AppName.exe" - skip tacitly
        End If  
next   
Exit function
    IsAppRunning = False
End Function


Do while IsAppRunning(AppName)
    Wscript.Sleep(1000) 'wait miliseconds
msgbox "Prozessis still running/not running (depends on wait for start/stop)!"
Loop


Wscript.quit
```

Hope you can help me with this code. I need it for various processes, so I call it "AppName" for better reference.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367567/close-process-when-a-separate-process-closes. You have Win32_ProcessStopTrace, Win32_ProcessStartTrace, and Win32_ProcessStartStopTrace.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, because the script should also work with non-admin rights and only for specific directory path

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/270c94a9-bf89-4680-b05e-9d81d51493db/kill-process-by-its-path?forum=netfxbcl Should offer ideas on process by path actions. With a bit of adjustment this could be used to monitor the process in a do while loop, and execute the desired action when the if condition is met (using if process count < 0 check)

Comment: I'm at work currently, otherwise I'd provide a full answer with the appropriate example.